# escaping an apostrophe in XML attributes

Tags: c#, xml

Trying to load some XML into a document:

```
<Custom AttributeA='' AttributeB='Bob' AttributeC='HUNTERS' COMPANY EMPLOYEES' 403B PLAN' />
```

Then when I try to add it to a document:

```
XmlDocument xmlCustom = new XmlDocument();
xmlCustom.LoadXml(customNode);
```

I end up getting an error message System.Xml.XmlException: 'COMPANY' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. 
The value of AttributeC is supposed to be: HUNTERS' COMPANY EMPLOYEES' 403B PLAN

I tried replacing the ' previously before loading the XML but it replaces ALL of the apostrophe's and AttributeA='' is equally invalid.

EDIT: Yes, I would agree on poorly formed but it is what I have to work with.

Comment: See my answer about escaping.

Comment: I have an evil 3rd party DLL which created this XML that I have no control over.  The question is invalid more or less by what folks have told me so far, I will be unable to correct my situation until I fix(REPLACE) the 3rd party method.  Since when cant I not close/delete my own questions :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
<Custom AttributeC="HUNTERS&apos; COMPANY EMPLOYEES'&apos; 403B PLAN"/>
```

or

```
<Custom AttributeC="HUNTERS' COMPANY EMPLOYEES' 403B PLAN"/>
```

or even

```
<Custom AttributeC='HUNTERS&apos; COMPANY EMPLOYEES&apos; 403B PLAN'/>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many many problems with this piece of markup.

This is no XML. XML uses double quotes for attributes (okay, I just learned single quotes are okay, too). But it requires equals-Signs between attribute name and value (see your last attribute). In addition, attribute names cannot contain whitespace, and MUST have a value assigned, unlike in HTML.

Oh, and if there is no closing tag, you have to end the line with `/>`, not just `>`.

If you want to have an apostrophe in your attributes, you can use escaping, like here:

```
<gangster name="George &quot;Shotgun&quot; Ziegler">
```

Or with single quotes (and an escaped single quote):

```
<ad text='I love McDonald&apos;s'>
```

Or by using double quotes when you want single quotes in the attributes:

```
<ad text="I love McDonald's">
```

Comment: I think it is, just poorly formed.

Comment: Right, it is far from being well formed.

Comment: You can also use simple quotes, but obviously can't mix them :-)

Answer (score 1):

Encode the apostrophe as `&apos;`

```
<Custom AttributeA='' AttributeB='Bob' AttributeC='HUNTERS&apos; COMPANY EMPLOYEES&apos; 403B PLAN' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are not allowed for attribute names. You must type something like this:

```
<Custom AttributeA='' AttributeB='Bob' AttributeC='HUNTERS&apos; COMPANY EMPLOYEES&apos; 403B PLAN'/>
```

Comment: -1, "HUNTERS' COMPANY EMPLOYEES' 403B PLAN" is the value of the AttributeC

Comment: @jutky - I didn't catch the needed semantics. I have corrected my answer.